# Internet Explorer compatibility issue displaying a link on a webpage

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my site, I have a link underneath the Google map on the right hand side called "View larger map". This link simply opens up a larger version of the Google map.

Ideally I want this link underneath the small map either on the left or right hand side. In Chrome and Firefox I have it perfect (on the left hand side underneath the map image). In IE 9 it moves up the page top left of the map image. 
I've been trying all night to get it to sit underneath the map image in either the left or right hand side in all browsers, but when I managed to get it working in IE it was broken in Chrome and FF. I'm now frustrated and am resigned to asking for help.

The website page in question is online here: http://stage.boarsheadgolfcentre.co.uk/Home/Contact

Currently it is setup exactly how I want it in Chrome, but IE is not displaying correctly.

Comment: try float: left; or float: right; in a tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `div` containing the map and the text to include `width: 350px`.

```
<div style="float: right; margin-top: -50px; width: 350px">
    <p>
        ...
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Saluce, I think I was a bit brain dead and never thought of that :-)